# retrieve quoted string using expression language

Tags: java, regex, string

How to retrieve the quoted value of a property.

suppose you have some expression like:

```
[html:text property="pqrs" styleClass="text" style="width:200px"].
```

And now i want to retrieve the value of **property**, **styleclass** and **style** ie "pqrs", "text" and "width:200px" respectively.

Can you guys please help me in this.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(\w+)\=\"(.*?)\"
```

The first capture group `(\w+)` gives you the attribute name, and the second capture group uses a non-aggressive operator to match things inside quotes.

Comment: if you can please write down the expression with the matcher and pettern method that should be used, will be a great help.

Comment: Thanks i got the answer, your expression works. Implementation using java code: String property =(string)="\"(.*?)\""; Pattern startingPattern = Pattern.compile(property);   if(match.find()){
    System.out.println("found");
    for(int j=0; j<match.groupCount(); j++){
     System.out.println(match.group(j));
    }

Comment: Sorry, my Java is also a bit rusty. But you sure should know how to create a regex and execute it, otherwise you probably shouldn't be using regex's in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the text in quotes, a non-greedy match should work:

```
".*?"
```

Comment: can you please write the matcher method that will return the quoted string using your expression. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Kuri - sorry, I've never written a non-trivial java program.  If you need more detail, hopefully someone will come here and answer your question.  I came here via the [regex] tag.